# If text or value starts with a character, run function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contains, startswith

I need to detect if the text in a span BEGINS WITH the letter "x" and run a function.  I read I can do it with "^" in strings - but having trouble making it work checking text...

```html
 <span>xfoo</span>
```

```js
if ($('span:contains(^"x")').length > 0) {
    alert ('there is text on this page starts with x');
}
```

Bonus points of I can also check the value of an input field...

Comment: Well for starters your span "starts with" a space...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to iterate over all the `<span>` elements, check the condition and run the code. Use `text()` to get the textContent of the element and `trim()` to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
$('span').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim().startsWith('x')) {
        alert('Check this span, it starts with x');

        // Use `$(this)` here to refer to the current <span>
    }
});
```

---

If there are many `<span>` elements in DOM, `:contains()` can be used to select only the elements having some string(*x*).

```
$('span:contains("x")').each(function() {
    ...
```

Comment: This works great, thank you!   Would something also work to check a value?  There's another spot on the page where I would like to check the value of an input field by using startsWith...

Comment: @user3390251 You can use similar code with `$('input')` and `.val()` instead of `text()` and it should work.

Comment: I'd add a class on these spans and select them by class instead of iterating over eeeeevery span.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Yes, that'd be faster, but really depends on OP's requirements. What if the markup is generated?

Comment: @Tushar even if it's generated, one should have control of what's generated :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to `trim()` the text to remove the leading/trailing whitespace. From there you could use `filter()` and `charAt(0)` to compare the first character. Something like this:

```
var $spans = $('span').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim().charAt(0) == 'x';
});

if ($spans.length) {
    console.log('Check these spans which start with x');
    $span.addClass('foo');
}
```

You could use `startsWith()` instead of `charAt()`, but beware that this has no support in any version of IE (or even under Chrome 41, FF 17 and Opera 28) without using a polyfill.

Answer (score 0):

using regx will help to validate the text.

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var pattern = new RegExp('^[x]');

if(pattern.test(s[0].innerText)){
    console.log('found match');
} 
else {
    console.log('not found')
}
```